# What permissions are required for NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress() to access the MAC address?

Tags: network-programming, mac-address

I have the following code below to access the current devices MAC address. When updating the application to android 11 and higher, NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress is now returning a null value. I believe it is a network permissions error but I am unsure what permissions to add or change? Code as follows:

```
try {
       byte[] macBytes = intf.getHardwareAddress();
       if (macBytes == null) {
           macAddress = "MAC Address Unknown";
       } else {
           // Deal with returned mac address here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android 10 it appears you can no longer access a devices Mac address. A potential alternative is fingerprintJS to get a devices unique id for use with identification.